# Filter two lists against each other using predicate with ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ramda.js

I have an array of rooms, each of which contain another array of `disabledDays` in which they cannot be booked for:

```
const rooms = [
  {
    disabledDays: [],
    title: 'roomOne'
  },
  {
    disabledDays: ['2019-07-10T01:00:00.000Z'],
    title: 'roomTwo'
  },
  {
    disabledDays: [
      '2019-07-08T01:00:00.000Z',
      '2019-07-09T01:00:00.000Z',
      '2019-07-02T01:00:00.000Z'
    ],
    title: 'roomThree'
  },
  {
    disabledDays: [],
    title: 'roomFour'
  }
];
```

I then also have a range of chosen dates which I would like to use to find  available rooms for:

```
const selectedDates = [
  '2019-07-06T01:00:00.000Z',
  '2019-07-07T01:00:00.000Z',
  '2019-07-08T01:00:00.000Z',
  '2019-07-09T01:00:00.000Z'
];
```

In this case I want to find `rooms` that have *none* of the `selectedDates` in their `disabledDays` array.

My attempt so far uses a combination of `map`, `reject` and `any`, however this doesn’t seem to return the full room as a result.

```
const result = map(
  room => reject(
    date => any(disabled => isSameDay(date, disabled), selectedDates),
    prop('disabledDays', room)
  ),
  rooms
)
```

I am using the `isSameDay` function from `date-fns` as a predicate to test whether the dates are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Ramda, I would use R.reject, and create a predicate with R.propSatisfies that uses R.any to match it agains the `selectedDates` with curried `dateFns.isSameDay`, and a flipped R.any:

```js
const { curry, reject, propSatisfies, any, pipe, flip } = R

const eqByDate = curry(dateFns.isSameDay)

const fn = selectedDates => reject(propSatisfies(
  any(pipe(
    eqByDate,
    flip(any)(selectedDates),
  )),
  'disabledDays',
))

const rooms = [{ disabledDays: [], title: 'roomOne' }, { disabledDays: ['2019-07-10T01:00:00.000Z'], title: 'roomTwo' }, { disabledDays: [ '2019-07-08T01:00:00.000Z', '2019-07-09T01:00:00.000Z', '2019-07-02T01:00:00.000Z' ], title: 'roomThree' }, { disabledDays: [], title: 'roomFour' } ];
const selectedDates = [ '2019-07-06T01:00:00.000Z', '2019-07-07T01:00:00.000Z', '2019-07-08T01:00:00.000Z', '2019-07-09T01:00:00.000Z' ];

const result = fn(selectedDates)(rooms)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the ES6, Lodash and Ramda versions of one approach. I went a different route with `filter` and `any/some` since that made somewhat more sense to me. I am sure you could also do it with `reject` but I am not sure you would start with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) since map would expect to return the same `length` array:

```js
const rooms = [{ disabledDays: [], title: 'roomOne' }, { disabledDays: ['2019-07-10T01:00:00.000Z'], title: 'roomTwo' }, { disabledDays: [ '2019-07-08T01:00:00.000Z', '2019-07-09T01:00:00.000Z', '2019-07-02T01:00:00.000Z' ], title: 'roomThree' }, { disabledDays: [], title: 'roomFour' } ];
const selectedDates = [ '2019-07-06T01:00:00.000Z', '2019-07-07T01:00:00.000Z', '2019-07-08T01:00:00.000Z', '2019-07-09T01:00:00.000Z' ];

let js = rooms.filter(({ disabledDays, title}) =>
  !disabledDays.some(d => selectedDates.some(s => dateFns.isSameDay(d,s))))

let lodash = _.filter(rooms, r => 
  !_.some(r.disabledDays, d => _.some(selectedDates, s => dateFns.isSameDay(d,s))))

let r = R.filter(r => !R.any(d => R.any(s => 
  dateFns.isSameDay(d,s), selectedDates), r.disabledDays), rooms)

console.log('js: ', js)
console.log('_: ', lodash)
console.log('R: ', r)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

I am sure that the Ramda version could be made more concise but I will leave that to the Ramda aficionados here.

Comment: Ah, it is the 2nd `any` I seemed to be missing. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

*I overlooked your dependency on `date-fns`. However if these are the strings you need to work with then a simple string comparison should do the job? If you need to work with `date-fns` then Ori Drori answer is probably what you want*

---

You can use `intersection` to find the common dates between two list of dates.

You can then build a predicate that will keep all rooms for which that there are no commons dates:

```js
const rooms = [
  {
    disabledDays: [],
    title: 'roomOne'
  },
  {
    disabledDays: ['2019-07-10T01:00:00.000Z'],
    title: 'roomTwo'
  },
  {
    disabledDays: [
      '2019-07-08T01:00:00.000Z',
      '2019-07-09T01:00:00.000Z',
      '2019-07-02T01:00:00.000Z'
    ],
    title: 'roomThree'
  },
  {
    disabledDays: [],
    title: 'roomFour'
  }
];


const selectedDates = [
  '2019-07-06T01:00:00.000Z',
  '2019-07-07T01:00:00.000Z',
  '2019-07-08T01:00:00.000Z',
  '2019-07-09T01:00:00.000Z'
];


const z = (dates, rooms) =>
  filter(propSatisfies(compose(isEmpty, intersection(dates)), 'disabledDays'), rooms);

console.log(
  z(selectedDates, rooms)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {intersection, filter, propSatisfies, compose, isEmpty} = R;</script>
```